# How to label code block evaluations in orgmode on html export?

Tags: html, css, org-mode

If I have a code block in orgmode, I can export its evaluation by using the `:exports both` option.

```
#+begin_src cpp -n :includes <iostream> :exports both
std::cout << "Hello there";
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello there
```

When I export to html (`C-c C-e h o`), the result block follows the code block. However, I  would like to more explicitly show that the 2nd block is the result of the first, with say, a simple label.

If I modify the above, like so:

```
#+begin_src cpp -n :includes <iostream> :exports both
std::cout << "Hello there";
#+end_src

Output:

#+RESULTS:
: Hello there
```

then the label "Output:" appears, but the result block appears twice -- once before the label, and once after. What's worse is that if I run the code within orgmode (`C-c C-c`), then a second result block is placed before the text label, "Output:". I suspect this is what's happening on export as well.

I have also noticed that when exporting to html, the result blocks are placed in a `pre` tags of class `example`. I thought I could modify the css with something like:

```
pre.example::before { content: "Output:"; }
```

but unfortunately, this places the text inside the `pre` block, and I can't add any line breaks.

Is there any simple way to add text labels to result blocks in either orgmode itself, or perhaps through css? I'd like to avoid javascript if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on reasonably recent org:

```
    #+name: foo
    #+begin_src cpp -n :includes <iostream> :exports both
    std::cout << "Hello there";
    #+end_src

    Output:

    #+RESULTS: foo
    : Hello there
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived backend for this like this:

```
(defun my-results (fixed-width contents info)
  "Transform a results block to make it more visible."
  (let ((results (org-element-property :results fixed-width))
    (format (elt (plist-get info :back-end) 2))
    (value (org-element-property :value fixed-width)))
    (cond 
     ((eq 'html format)
      (format "<pre>Output:<br> %s</pre>" value)))))


(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-html 'html
  :translate-alist '((fixed-width . my-results)))

(browse-url (org-export-to-file 'my-html (concat (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".html")))
```

Comment: If I put this code in my `.emacs` file, I get the error message `Symbol's function definition is void: org-export-define-derived-backend
`. I supposed it could have been due to the fact that my org-mode version was `8.2.something`, so I upgraded to `8.3.4`. I still get this error after upgrading.

Comment: That should be defined in ox.el. Maybe add (require 'ox) above that code.

Comment: that isn't where you need to add it. you need to put it in your .emacs file.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you said. If I add your code to my `.emacs` with `(require 'ox)` beforehand, I get an error along the lines of `Wrong argument type, stringp nil`